# Turbo C++ compile error "too many types in declaration"

Tags: c++, types, turbo-c++

whenever I compile this program, I get an error saying "Too many types in decleration on line 13". I do not see any possible syntax errors but still I am facing this issue.

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>

class currency
{
    private:
    int rupee,paise;
    int total;
    public:
    void getdata(int r,int p);
    void display();

}
void currency::getdata(int r, int p){

    rupee=r;
    paise=p;
    total=r*100+p;

}
void currency::display(){

cout<<rupee<<" Rupees"<<" and "<<paise<<"Paise"<<endl;
cout<<"Converted value="<<total;

}

int main(){

    currency c;
        c.getdata(5,25);
        c.display();
        getch();
        return 0;

}
```

[image: the error]

Comment: Which is line 13?

Comment: There's been a lot of Turbo C++ questions lately which is really quite odd. What's inspired this resurgence?

Comment: void currency::getdata(int r, int p){ line 13, where the function is being declared

Comment: For starters, you're missing a semicolon after the body of `class currency`.

Comment: Don't use TurboC++ (an obsolete, non standard conforming, compiler). Use at least C++11 or even better C++17 with a recent compiler like [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) or [Clang/LLVM](http://clang.llvm.org/). Both are free software.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch C++17 is really where it's at, and all modern compilers support it.

Comment: Indeed, but when learning C++ there is a huge difference between C++11 and older standards (and what TurboC++ support). The difference between C++11 & C++17 is much smaller

Comment: This takes me back to the nostalgia of 1999.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There needs to be a semicolon to terminate the class definition:

```
}  ;   // semicolon needed here.
void currency::getdata( ...
```

Otherwise, it looks like this to the compiler:

```
class blahblah {int etc, etc1; int etc2; } void currency::getdata (...
```

Comment: Oh thank you, I skipped the semicolon unknowingly because I am used to using JavaScript where semicolons aren't that mandatory in most cases.

Answer (score 1):

At a guess, I'd say the root problem is the missing semicolon after the body of `class currency`.

Recall than in C/C++, you can define an object like as part of a class or struct definition, like this:

```
struct foo
{
    int bar;
} FooObj;
```

This creates an variable `FooObj` of type `struct foo`.

So in your code, the following:

```
class currency
{
    /* ... */
}
void currency::getdata(int r, int p){
    /* ... */
}
```

... is equivalent to this:

```
class currency
{
    /* ... */
} void currency::getdata(int r, int p){
    /* ... */
}
```

...which is equivalent to this:

```
class currency
{
    /* ... */
};

currency void currency::getdata(int r, int p){
    /* ... */
}
```

So it looks like you've given function `getdata` two return types, which would explain the error.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you missed a semicolon after the class definition;
Classes are not like functions, but similar to struct definitions in C, you need to put a semicolon after the `}`. 
Such as:

```
class A {};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you'll put a semicolon `";"` after ending class currency{ } your program will be compiled and you'll get the correct output.

```
class abc
{
   ...
};
```